# Flutter: Type "A" is not a sup type of type "B" even though B extends A

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to assign an instance of class `NumberTrivia`  to an instance of class `NumberTriviaModel` but it is giving me the error:
`The argument type 'NumberTrivia' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'NumberTriviaModel'.`. So I tried to cast it but now I get an uncaught error. Reso code could assign NumberTrivia to NumberTriviaModel  before. But it was an older dart version and it can't be done the same way now. Now the main question is how to do so in the newer dart version.

```
void main() {
  
  NumberTrivia remoteTrivia = NumberTrivia(text : "Text", number : 5);
  cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia as NumberTriviaModel);
}

class NumberTrivia {
  final String text;
  final int number;

  NumberTrivia({
    required this.text,
    required this.number,
  });


}


class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {
  NumberTriviaModel({
    required String text,
    required int number,
  }) : super(text: text, number: number);

  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'text': text,
      'number': number,
    };
  }
}

void cacheNumberTrivia(NumberTriviaModel triviaToCache) {
    print(triviaToCache.number);
}
```

but it's giving me the following error

```
Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'NumberTrivia': type 'NumberTrivia' is not a subtype of type 'NumberTriviaModel'
```

Comment: Error explains it quite well

Comment: I'm asking for solution @KęstutisRamulionis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Downcasting** is not safe: the extending-object may have additional and thus missing properties when casting down. Which is why it results in an error.

As an alternative, one can use a special constructor for cloning / copying an object:

```dart
void main() {
  NumberTrivia remoteTrivia = NumberTrivia(text: "Text", number: 5);
  cacheNumberTrivia(NumberTriviaModel.copy(remoteTrivia));
}

class NumberTrivia {
  final String text;
  final int number;

  NumberTrivia({
    required this.text,
    required this.number,
  });
}

class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {

  NumberTriviaModel.copy(NumberTrivia nt)        // HERE
      : this(text: nt.text, number: nt.number);

  NumberTriviaModel({
    required String text,
    required int number,
  }) : super(text: text, number: number);

  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'text': text,
      'number': number,
    };
  }
}

void cacheNumberTrivia(NumberTriviaModel triviaToCache) {
  print(triviaToCache.number);
}
```

**Before Edit**

```
Instance of 'NumberTrivia':
  type 'NumberTrivia' is not a subtype of type 'NumberTriviaModel'
```

This means that `NumberTrivia` does not extend `NumberTriviaModel`.

Looking at the code, it is the other way around. `NumberTriviaModel` extends `NumberTrivia`, `NumberTriviaModel` is a sub-type `NumberTrivia`:

```dart
class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {
      ! SUBTYPE                 ! TYPE
```

Your headline states `Type "A" is not a sup type of type "B" even though A extends B`. But the code does not reflect that.

Instead, the code can be described as `Type "A" is not a sup type of type "B" BECAUSE B extends A`.

Comment: This was a mistake from me. It's not the main problem here. Reso code could assign ```NumberTrivia``` to ```NumberTriviaModel ``` before. But it was an older dart version and it can't be done the same way now. Now the main question is how to do so in the newer dart version. Focus on the main problem please!

Comment: @MU'menAhmed People are focusing on the problem you are describing. If the description is wrong, they will not be able to help you. Please update your post to describe the actual problem the code has.

Comment: The post is edited. Please edit the answer or add new one.

Comment: @MU'menAhmed Done, good luck!

Comment: So using a mapper is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling the method is wrong. Here A extends B. If you want to access method of A you need to use instance of A. If you have added method in B and tried to access via instance of A, you can use it.

```
void main() {
  
  NumberTriviaModel remoteTrivia = NumberTriviaModel(text : "Text", number : 5);
  cacheNumberTrivia(remoteTrivia as NumberTriviaModel);
}

class NumberTrivia {
  final String text;
  final int number;

  NumberTrivia({
    required this.text,
    required this.number,
  });


}


class NumberTriviaModel extends NumberTrivia {
  NumberTriviaModel({
    required String text,
    required int number,
  }) : super(text: text, number: number);

  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'text': text,
      'number': number,
    };
  }
}

void cacheNumberTrivia(NumberTriviaModel triviaToCache) {
    print(triviaToCache.number);
}
```